# What is this type of MD5?

Tags: android, hash, md5, logcat, md5sum

guys i have a code who hash string and object but when i hash the code online on any website encrypt its come out different from the other one in the code i want to know what is makes the other MD5 code different from this online

the md5 code:

```
public static String md5(String paramString){
if (Utils.isNullOrEmpty(paramString)) {
  return "";
}
try
{
  Object localObject1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
  if (localObject1 != null) {
    ((MessageDigest)localObject1).update(paramString.getBytes());
  }
  paramString = ((MessageDigest)localObject1).digest();
  localObject1 = new StringBuilder();
  int j = paramString.length;
  int i = 0;
  while (i < j)
  {
    String str = Integer.toHexString(paramString[i] & 0xFF);
    if (str.length() == 1) {
      ((StringBuilder)localObject1).append('0');
    }
    ((StringBuilder)localObject1).append(str);
    i += 1;
  }
}
catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException localNoSuchAlgorithmException)
{
  Object localObject2;
  for (;;)
  {
    localNoSuchAlgorithmException.printStackTrace();
    localObject2 = null;
  }
  return ((StringBuilder)localObject2).toString();
}
```

he take two value

```
public static String generateChkSum(HashMap<String, Object> paramHashMap)  {
paramHashMap = a(paramHashMap);
Log.d("CheckSum Before Concat ::::::::::   ", paramHashMap);
paramHashMap = md5(paramHashMap);
paramHashMap = md5(paramHashMap + "^" + AppConstants.a);
Log.d("CheckSum After Concat  ::::::::::   ", paramHashMap);
return paramHashMap;
```

the logcat:

```
01-27 02:25:08.440 2369-3661/com.test.app D/CheckSum Before Concat ::::::::::: kinghema^1784e7fe94d4750df3af902489489b77
01-27 02:25:08.440 2369-3661/com.test.app D/CheckSum After Concat  ::::::::::: 781973a6c9d36f18d9f02f80dc2e5d6e
```

and the result is :781973a6c9d36f18d9f02f80dc2e5d6e
but if we take the 2 value and hash them online normally:
39cec39f604f5a4380bae1f00c7404b6

so my question is what is this type of hashing he use? whats is the difference between this code and the online code what is the method he use?

Comment: Interesting approach to use a type safe language. Obviously you don't want to get help from the compiler. Also the endless loop in the catch clause is interesting.

Comment: its not like that i see this example of MD5 i was searching for it but i surprised he is making a new type of Hash?

Comment: and the value two after kinghema^ is password i hashed online

Comment: So you decompiled some Android code and now you want us to do the rest of your work for you and tell you how it works?

Comment: no you get it wrong read the comments above you @JamesKPolk